# Inset Faces gone wrong

Tags: modeling

I wanted to Inset a Faces on a Square but instead it turning into like

this :
[image]

actually i want the face to get inset like :

[image]

where we can see the botton and the top also getting pull but mine only the side and little on the top and bottom.

can anyone tell me how can i make it like the 2nd picture.

Comment: hello, have you applied the scale of your object in Object mode?

Comment: you mean the ctrl+A and Scale ? no i havent i might wanna try

Comment: yes, it must be your problem here

Comment: Possible duplicate vertices, too. (The result of a previous, abandoned inset?)

Comment: it seems after applying scale i can instaly inset it and it turn into normal as before i got this problem on the other model for 3 months already i cant believe it was applying scale.